# Add Chi-Squared Distribution to Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $z \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$. What is the distribution of $z^2+6z+1$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

$(z+3)^2$ is a noncentral $\chi_1^2$, so $(z+3)^2-8$ is a noncentral $\chi_1^2$ with a location and scale shifts.

Comment: Sorry, it would be right if the variance were one. It's easier to just note that $E(z^2)+6Ez+1 =Vz+\mu^2+6\mu+1=\sigma^2+\mu^2+6\mu+1$.